# MVC Globalization for DisplayName and DisplayFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, globalization

I am developing a multilingual (English, Arabic) application using MVC. This application should display both the labels and the data based on the resources files.

database is designed to store the translated fields in same tables for example

```
  Gender[Id, Name,ArabicName]
  Person[Id,FirstName,FatherName,FamilyName,ArabicFirstName,
           ArabicFatherName,ArabicFamilyName,GenderId]
```

I managed to display all `dropdownlist` based on the resources by switching between `Name` and `ArabicName` fields using:

```
        ViewBag.Gender= new SelectList(mEntities.Genders.ToList(), "Id",
                                       Resources.Global.Name);
    // Name value in the Global.resx is Name and in Global.ar.resx is ArabicName
```

and also by displaying the `LabelFor` using:

```
[Display(Name="FirstName", ResourceType =typeof(Resources.Global))]
public string FirstName{get;set;}
```

My question, is it possible to switch between the `FirstName` **value** and `ArabicFirstName` using `DisplayFor` and how to achieve this in MVC?

for example to display:  `FirstName = Antony for english , ArabicFirstName = انطوان for arabic`

Comment: You can Use Same DisplayFor Add Some thing like this In Model and Use FirstName1 insted of FirstName [NotMapped]
 public string FirstName1 { get { return <namespace>.Dictionary.Dict.ResourceManager.GetString(FirstName); } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following workaround to make things work

1. To distinguish between the labels and data values in resource file I used the convension:

`FirstName` stands for labels and `FirstNameResource` stands for data

example the resource file will be like:

```
   FirstName => value = First Name (for english), الاسم الاول (for arabic)
   FirstNameResource = > value = FirstName ( for english) , ArabicFirstName (for arabic)
```

2. I coded the following HtmlHelper

   ```
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayResourceFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
       Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
   {
       var rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Global", 
           System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
       var resource = rm.GetString(string.Format("{0}Resource", 
           ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)));
       var value = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.GetViewDataInfo(resource).Value.ToString();
       return MvcHtmlString.Create(value);
   }
   ```
3. You can use this extension as following:

   @Html.DisplayResourceFor(m=>m.FirstName)

This workaround helped me to solve the problem, but maybe there is another straight forward solution.